# How to deal with source that emits Future[T]?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Let's say I have some iterator:

```
val nextElemIter: Iterator[Future[Int]] = Iterator.continually(...)
```

And I want to build a source from that iterator:

```
val source: Source[Future[Int], NotUsed] =
  Source.fromIterator(() => nextElemIter)
```

So now my source emits `Future`s. I have never seen futures being passed between stages in Akka docs or anywhere else, so instead, I could always do something like this:

```
val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = 
  Source.fromIterator(() => nextElemIter).mapAsync(1)(identity /* was n => n */)
```

And now I have a regular source that emits `T` instead of `Future[T]`. But this feels hacky and wrong.

What's the proper way to deal with such situations?

Comment: I think that `mapAsync` is perfectly fine here. After all, it is intended exactly for this purpose - flattening futures into streams.

Comment: `mapAsync(1)(identity)` is proper way of doing it.

Comment: @expert edited.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I was more with the impression that non-future values should pass between stages, and `mapAsync` was more for futures that get created _inside_ a stage, not coming already as a future from the _outside_. I might be wrong though. It just seems odd that there's no `Source` builder which flattens futures by itself

Answer (score 5):

Answering your question directly: I agree with Vladimir's comment that there is nothing "hacky" about using `mapAsync` for the purpose you described.  I can't think of any more direct way to unwrap the `Future` from around your underlying `Int` values.

Answering your question indirectly...

**Try to stick with Futures**

Streams, as a concurrency mechanism, are incredibly useful when backpressure is required.  However, pure `Future` operations have their place in applications as well.

If your `Iterator[Future[Int]]` is going to produce a known, limited, number of `Future` values then you may want to stick with using the Futures for concurrency.

Imagine you want to filter, map, & reduce the `Int` values.

```
def isGoodInt(i : Int) : Boolean = ???         //filter
def transformInt(i : Int) : Int = ???          //map
def combineInts(i : Int, j : Int) : Int = ???  //reduce
```

Futures provide a direct way of using these functions:

```
val finalVal : Future[Int] = 
  Future sequence { 
    for {
      f <- nextElemIter.toSeq  //launch all of the Futures
      i <- f if isGoodInt(i)
    } yield transformInt(i)
  } map (_ reduce combineInts)
```

Compared with a somewhat indirect way of using the Stream as you suggested:

```
val finalVal : Future[Int] = 
  Source.fromIterator(() => nextElemIter)
        .via(Flow[Future[Int]].mapAsync(1)(identity))
        .via(Flow[Int].filter(isGoodInt))
        .via(Flow[Int].map(transformInt))
        .to(Sink.reduce(combineInts))
        .run()
```